# Prevent HTML form from submitting with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, mailchimp

I have a subscription form using mailchimp.

I've written a JS validation method to stop hotmail/yahoo/gmail accounts from registering only I cant get it to work? No matter what ive tried the form action kicks in and the JS is ignored...

**Form Tag**

```
<form id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" action="action here" method="post" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" novalidate="" target="_blank">
```

**JS Validator**

```
$('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').on('submit', function (e) {

var inputString = $('#mce-EMAIL').val();
var gmail = "gmail";
var yahoo = "yahoo";
var hotmail = "hotmail";

if (inputString.indexOf(gmail) > -1) {
   alert('Sorry, Gmail accounts are unable to subscribe');
    return false;

} else if (inputString.indexOf(yahoo) > -1) {

    alert('Sorry, Yahoo accounts are unable to subscribe');return false;
} else if (inputString.indexOf(hotmail) > -1) {

    alert('Sorry, Hotmail accounts are unable to subscribe'); return false;
} else {
    return true;
}

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to prevent the form from submitting by disabling the default action of the event:

```
$('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    . . .
});
```

You could prevent it from firing right away, and then manually trigger submit later, or you could call [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) only in the case of an error.